# rails mailer default :to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I found all my `UserMailer` functions send mail to `user.email`, and I was looking out for a way to set it as default, anybody tried out or thought of similar hack before?

Answer (score 0):

Generally what I have is instead of all my mailer classes inheriting `ActionMailer::Base`, I inherit them with my common mailer class which inherits ActionMailer

There in you can specify the `default :to`  which will be used for all you mailer classes..